# Calculate aggregates in a bucket in Upsert MongoDB update statement

Tags: mongodb

My application gets measurements from a device that should be stored in a MongoDB database. Each measurement contains values for several probes of the device.
The measurements should displayed in an aggregation for a certain amount of time. I'm using the [Bucket pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern) in order to prepare the aggregates and simplify indexing and querying.

The following sample shows a document:

```
{
    "DeviceId": "Device1",
    "StartTime": 100, "EndTime": 199,
    "Measurements": [
        { "timestamp": 100, "probeValues": [ { "id": "1", "t": 30 }, { "id": "2", "t": 67 } ] },
        { "timestamp": 101, "probeValues": [ { "id": "1", "t": 32 }, { "id": "2", "t": 67 } ] },
        { "timestamp": 102, "probeValues": [ { "id": "1", "t": 34 }, { "id": "2", "t": 55 } ] },
        { "timestamp": 103, "probeValues": [ { "id": "1", "t": 27 }, { "id": "2", "t": 30 } ] }
    ],
    "probeAggregates": [
        { "id": "1", "cnt": 4, "total": 123 },
        { "id": "2", "cnt": 4, "total": 219 }
    ]
}
```

Updating the values and calculating the aggregates in a single request works well if the document already exists (1st block: query, 2nd: update, 3rd: options):

```
{
    "DeviceId": "Device1",
    "StartTime": 100,
    "EndTime": 199
},
{ 
    $push: {
        "Measurements": { 
            "timestamp": 103, 
            "probeValues": [ { "id": "1", "t": 27 }, { "id": "2", "t": 30 } ]
            }
    }, 
    $inc: {
        "probeAggregates.$[probeAggr1].cnt": 1,
        "probeAggregates.$[probeAggr1].total": 27,
        "probeAggregates.$[probeAggr2].cnt": 1,
        "probeAggregates.$[probeAggr2].total": 30
    }
},
{ 
    arrayFilters: [
        { "probeAggr1.id": "1" }, 
        { "probeAggr2.id": "2" }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to extend the statement to do a `upsert` if the document does not exist yet. However, if I do not change the update statement at all, there is the following error:

> The path 'probeAggregates' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.

If I try to prepare the `probeAggregates` array in case of an insert (e.g. by using `$setOnInsert` or `$addToSet`), this leads to another error:

> Updating the path 'probeAggregates.$[probeAggr1].cnt' would create a conflict at 'probeAggregates'

Both errors can be explained and seem legit. One way to solve this would be to change the document structure and create one document per device, timeframe and probe and by that simplify the required update statement. In order to keep the number of documents low, I'd rather solve this by changing the update statement. **Is there a way to create a valid document in an upsert?**

(as I'm just learning to use a document db, feel free to share your experience in the comments on whether it is a good goal to keep the number of documents low in real world scenarios)